# How to call Internal class methods through Interface in DLL

Tags: c#, interface, xamarin.ios, abstract-class

In my Xamarin.iOS binding project's, I have following interface defined in my ApiDefinition.cs

```
[BaseType(typeof(LSMAHandler))]
[Protocol, Model]
interface LSMAHandlerRegister
```

It has generated LSMAHandlerRegister.g.cs in my project/obj/Debug/ios/project. This file contains followings

1. public interface ILSMAHandlerRegister : INativeObject,
   IDisposable,SightCallBinding.ILSMAHandler
2. internal sealed class LSMAHandlerRegisterWrapper : BaseWrapper,
   ILSMAHandlerRegister
3. public unsafe abstract partial class LSMAHandlerRegister :
   LSMAHandler, ILSMAHandlerRegister

I have added the generated DLL to my xamarin.ios project. Now I want to call RegisterWithURL method in above class. But the implementation of that method only available in internal wrapper class. How can I call to this method within my Xamarin.iOS project?

Answer (score 1):

Simple anwser - you can't. Internal classes are not visible in dll.
There are some things you can do though.

First of all think why this class is internal. There may be an important reason for this. The things you can do (you have to have access to this project)

- make class and interfaces public (maybe there is no reason for it to be internal)
- use `InternalsVisibleTo` https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute?view=netframework-4.8 - note however, that this is considered a bad practice and should not be done. One exception is test project. You can show internals to test project. That maybe sometimes ok.

create other public class that make use of this internal one, for example:

```
public class MyPublicHelper
{
    public void CallMyInternalMethod()
    {
        MyInternalClass obj = new MyInternalClass();
        obj.MyInternalMethod();
    }
}
```